# Labeling small strata in alluvial plot - different variables on columns/axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting problems with applying `ggrepel()` in an alluvial plot with different variables on columns. Some observations are so small, I need `ggrepel` to make them readable.

Because there are three columns, I want to apply different `ggrepel()` functions to each column:
Left (`region`): Align lables to the left of axis
Middle (`supplySector`): Do nothing (i.e. leave text in axis)
Right (`demandSector`): Align to right of axis.

I've found these issues:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/labels.html

and

[How to align and label the stratum in ggalluvial using ggrepel (or otherwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68487536/how-to-align-and-label-the-stratum-in-ggalluvial-using-ggrepel-or-otherwise)

Difference is: these examples only have 2 columns, and also columns made of the same variable (but subset of the variable). Previous published fixes are through an `ifelse()`, selecting a subset within the variable.

ReprEx:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(region = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                 supplySector = c("coal","gas","wind","coal","gas","wind"),
                 demandSector = c("resid","indus","ag","resid","indus","ag"),
                 Freq = 20*runif(6)); df  

p<- ggplot(df, aes(y = Freq, axis1 = region, axis2 = supplySector, axis3=demandSector, label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = demandSector), width = 1/12, color="black", alpha=0.8) +
  ggalluvial::geom_stratum(width = 1/3, fill = "grey70", color = "grey10", alpha=1) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Region", "Supply Sector", "Demand Sector"), expand = c(0.3,0),drop=F) +
  scale_y_continuous("Frequency (n)")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I've tried to feed the `colnames(df) == "region"` to get a true/false vector into

```
p +  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
  aes(label = ifelse(colnames(df) == "region", as.character(region), NA)),
  stat = "stratum", size = 4, direction = "y", nudge_x = -.5
)
```

I would then repeat this for `aes(label = ifelse(colnames(df) == "demandSector"` with `nudge_x = 1.5`.

[image: Current design, with left alignment of lables. Supply needs to stay within axis, demand needs to align to right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I got you wrong. But after a closer look at your example I would call it a duplicate to my answer you linked in your post.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggalluvial)

p +  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
  aes(label = ifelse(after_stat(x) == 1, as.character(after_stat(stratum)), NA)),
  stat = "stratum", size = 4, direction = "y", nudge_x = -.5
) +  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
  aes(label = ifelse(after_stat(x) == 2, as.character(after_stat(stratum)), NA)),
  stat = "stratum", size = 4, direction = "y", nudge_x = 0
) +  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
  aes(label = ifelse(after_stat(x) == 3, as.character(after_stat(stratum)), NA)),
  stat = "stratum", size = 4, direction = "y", nudge_x = +.5
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Stefan. This is exactly what I needed. I understood that the `after_stat(x) == 2` would select the second option within the "X" variable (or category). But, it seems you can select the axis on itself, without mentioning the variable.  Maybe we need to clarify this in your answer. 

Sorry for the duplicate question. My suggestion is to leave this one as an additional example, and link it on your question too? 

Or we can make a complete addition to your answer and remove this one?

Comment: Het Hendrik. Everything fine. I will close the question as a duplicate. In that case it will be linked to the other question. And yes. You are probably right that my former answer on using ggrepel should be clarified. As far as I could remember the only way to make ggrepe work with ggalluvial was to condition on axis position. I encountered a similar issue some days ago. I will check that out and edit my former answer. Best S.